# How to handle subviews of UITabBarController when interactivePopGesture (like Flipboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, interactivepopgesture

I'd like to have an underline that indicates which item was selected. It slides to any other items whenever the item was tapped. Therefore, I added a subview to the custom `UITabBarController` and set the animation. Then I use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to hide the tab bar when pushed. However, the underline seems not combined with the custom `UITabBarController`.

How to handle the subview so it is always on top even when using the back gesture? This **Flipboard** app capture is what I want to do.

[image: capture]

**Edit:**

```
CustomTabBarController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create underline view
    CGRect tabBarFrame = self.tabBar.frame;
    CGFloat itemWidth = (CGFloat)CGRectGetWidth(tabBarFrame) / MIN(5, self.tabBar.items.count);
    CGFloat originX = (CGFloat)itemWidth * self.selectedIndex;
    CGRect underlineFrame = CGRectMake(originX, CGRectGetMaxY(tabBarFrame) - 3.0f, itemWidth, 3.0f);

    self.underlineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:underlineFrame];
    self.underlineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.underlineView];
}

#pragma mark - UITabBarDelegate

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSUInteger itemIndex = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:item];
    CGRect underlineFrame = self.underlineView.frame;
    CGFloat originX = (CGFloat)CGRectGetWidth(self.underlineView.frame) * itemIndex;

    // underline shifting animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.underlineView.frame = CGRectMake(originX, underlineFrame.origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(underlineFrame), CGRectGetHeight(underlineFrame));
                     }];
}

CustomTableViewController.m
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
```

`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` hides the tab bar but its subview (the underline view).
If I hide it by myself and show it in `viewWillAppear`, the underline view does not look like on top of the tab bar.

[image: capture]

Comment: You should start by showing some of your code so we can help. I can't see from the picture why yours might not be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround. To override the method `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`, then you can add an alternative view for tab bar's subviews.

```
sourceViewController.m

- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    [super hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];

    CustomTabBarController *tabBarController = (CustomTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;

    if (tabBarController.underlineView.isHidden) {

        CGRect tabBarBounds = tabBarController.tabBar.bounds;
        CGFloat underlineHeight = CGRectGetHeight(tabBarController.underlineView.frame);
        CGFloat itemWidth = (CGFloat)CGRectGetWidth(tabBarBounds) / MIN(5, tabBarController.tabBar.items.count);
        CGFloat originX = (CGFloat)itemWidth * tabBarController.selectedIndex;

        UIView *alternativeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 
                                                                CGRectGetMaxY(tabBarBounds) - underlineHeight,
                                                                itemWidth,
                                                                underlineHeight)];
        alternativeView.tag = tabBarController.underlineViewTag;
        alternativeView.backgroundColor = tabBarController.underlineView.backgroundColor;
        [tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:alternativeView];
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CustomTabBarController *tabBarController = (CustomTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;

    if (tabBarController.underlineView.isHidden) {
        tabBarController.underlineView.hidden = NO;

        NSInteger underlineViewTag = tabBarController.underlineViewTag;
        UIView *alternativeView = [tabBarController.tabBar viewWithTag:underlineViewTag];
        [alternativeView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Don't forget the case that `interactivePopGesture` failure to popover view controller, the alternative view still be added to tab bar. So remove it at destination view controller if needed.

```
destinationViewController.m

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CustomTabBarController *tabBarController = (CustomTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;
    NSInteger underlineViewTag = tabBarController.underlineViewTag;
    UIView *alternativeView = [tabBarController.tabBar viewWithTag:underlineViewTag];

    if (alternativeView) [alternativeView removeFromSuperview];
}
```